# How to remove the contents in Cache directory?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

In my cache directory I have a folder named **Example**. That **Example** folder has subfolders `CSS`, `JS`. I want to remove the `CSS` subfolder.

If I use this code, the entire **Example** folder is removed:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *cacheFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCacheDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 
NSError *error = nil;

for (NSString *fileName in [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:cacheFolderPath error:&error])

{
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[cacheFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] error:&error];

}
```

Comment: do you have your css, js files inside a a subfolder or at root of caches dir?

Comment: those css,js are sub folders of example folder i want to delete that css sub folder...@cyberpawn

Comment: than you can simply delete those subfolders one by one, no need to delete all caches directory

Comment: I am new to this i am not getting how to delete the css sub folder please help me out...@cyberpawn

Comment: please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860583/how-to-overwrite-contents-of-document-directory-to-contents-of-cache-directory/13861232#13861232

Answer (score 8):

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *cacheFolderPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *dir = [cacheFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourCSSSUBFolderName"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:dir error:nil];
```

You can do the same for any other directories you want to delete!

Later if you want to add those files than first create that subfolder and than add your files for e-g:

```
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dirPath=[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourCSSSUBFolderName"];
NSFileManager *fileManger=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManger fileExistsAtPath:dirPath])
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [fileManger createDirectoryAtPath:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
}
// now add the directories
NSString *filePath = [dirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Yourfile.extension"];
[yourData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write to file
```

Comment: Hmm now i deleted those css,js sub folders in example folder in caches ...now i want to add css,js to same cache directory which are present in document directory as sub folders in expample1 folder...@cyberpawn

Comment: little bit confusion i removed those files okay...I will tell clearly i removed those Css,js sub folder in example folder which is present in cache directory rite ..thats perfect why i removed is when new update is present i just downloading the new example folder in document directory in that updated css,js are present now i want to add those new css,js to the cache directory ,,hope u got it and help me...@cyberpawn